# DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() / "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've got a large Google Docs file (containing comments and tracked changes). Accessing it from a larger Apps Script project failed with the message

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

This seems to be related to simply trying to get the active document, i.e. a function just with this

```
function myFunction() {
   var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
}
```

also fails with the above error. Now, when I create a copy of the document WITH COMMENTS/CHANGES, the error persists. But, if I create a copy WITHOUT comments and changes, the error goes away. So there must be something about the comments/changes in the document that causes the `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` to fail.

Any ideas?

P.S. - I will obviously try to isolate the problem in the document further, but the document is long (150 pages), so it will take me some time.

Comment: ..... and the problem has now gone away, i.e. the script now works on the full document with comments. The error had persisted all day, so I eventually tried to track it down.

Comment: ... and the problem is back. Same characteristics as before - it only affects one document, but in that one document, DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); fails. Any ideas?